# Error in connecting to Google Cloud SQL com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory casting

Tags: java, mysql, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactory

The above error occurs when Java Web application deploys to google cloud and run it. This error occurs when retrieve values to database or insert to databse (login, register). Why that error occurs and how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Database Connection :

```
public static DataSource getDBConnection() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();


        config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", properties.getProperty(CommonConstants.DATABASE_NAME)));
        config.setUsername(properties.getProperty(CommonConstants.USERNAME)); 
        config.setPassword(properties.getProperty(CommonConstants.PASSWORD)); 

        config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", properties.getProperty(CommonConstants.CLOUD_INSTANCE));

        DataSource pool = new HikariDataSource(config);

        return pool;
    }
```

Calling method :

```
 private static Connection connection;
    private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    private static DataSource pool = ConnectDB.getDBConnection();

    @Override
    public int validate(String userId, String password) {
        int status = 0;

        try {
            connection = pool.getConnection();

            String sql = QueryUtil.queryByID(CommonConstants.QUERY_USER_VALIDATE);

            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, userId);

            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()) {
                if(password.equals(rs.getString(1))) {
                    status = 1;
                }
            }
            try {
                if (preparedStatement != null) {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
            }

        } catch (SQLException | IOException | org.xml.sax.SAXException
                | ParserConfigurationException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        }

        return status;
    }
```

Stack Trace(Related to Login) :

```
Problem accessing /login. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.washpoint.servlet.login.doPost(login.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception: 
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:595)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:581)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at com.washpoint.util.ConnectDB.getDBConnection(ConnectDB.java:42)
    at com.washpoint.service.UserServiceImple.<clinit>(UserServiceImple.java:23)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3288)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:295)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactory
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3286)
    ... 52 more
Caused by:
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception: 
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:595)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:581)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at com.washpoint.util.ConnectDB.getDBConnection(ConnectDB.java:42)
    at com.washpoint.service.UserServiceImple.<clinit>(UserServiceImple.java:23)
    at com.washpoint.servlet.login.doPost(login.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3288)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:295)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactory
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3286)
    ... 52 more
Caused by:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3288)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:295)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at com.washpoint.util.ConnectDB.getDBConnection(ConnectDB.java:42)
    at com.washpoint.service.UserServiceImple.<clinit>(UserServiceImple.java:23)
    at com.washpoint.servlet.login.doPost(login.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactory
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3286)
    ... 52 more
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactory
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3286)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:295)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at com.washpoint.util.ConnectDB.getDBConnection(ConnectDB.java:42)
    at com.washpoint.service.UserServiceImple.<clinit>(UserServiceImple.java:23)
    at com.washpoint.servlet.login.doPost(login.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to import `jdbc-socket-factory-core`. It's a parent dependency, it's already pulled in from `mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8`. [Here is an example of the dependencies you need to have in your `pom.xml`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet/pom.xml#L52-L66).
2. You shouldn't need to cast the SocketFactory at all. Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet/src/main/java/com/example/cloudsql/ConnectionPoolContextListener.java#L51-L101), which shows how to create a pool that uses the Socket Factory. Take special note of L60, which shows how to specify the SocketFactory.

Comment: I have tried with that. But the same error occurs. I have edited the question. Can you please check it.

Comment: I have created this with Flexible Java Project

Comment: Did you remove the outdated dependency on jdbc-socket-factory-core? It's also helpful if you post the stacktrace of the error, which often contains helpful information.

Comment: This is the full stack trace (Login) . The last cause for the error is the error that I mentioned above. I have updated the question

Comment: I have updated the dependencies according to your recommendation. However the error still remains.

Comment: @YasiruRandika it sounds like you might have some additional dependencies (that aren't shown in your question) creating conflicts. I'm unable to replicate this error using this Application: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet . It includes instructions for deploying if you want to try it yourself

You may want to make sure you are using `mvn clean` when compiling, as well as checking for extra downstream dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree`.