# Use Cloud SQL Instance connection name with Hibernate EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect an old MVC Java web-app to the Cloud SQL using provided instance connection name following steps from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-mysql.md

Related part of the code looks like:

```
      JDBCDriverInfo driverInfo = databaseInfo.getJDBCDriverInfo();

      try {
         Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
         properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", driverInfo.getJDBCUrl());
         properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", driverInfo.getJDBCDriver());

         String username = databaseInfo.getUsername();
         if (username != null && !username.isEmpty()) {
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", username);
         }

         String password = databaseInfo.getPassword();
         if (password != null && !password.isEmpty()) {
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);
         }

         EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AppPU", properties);
         DBFactoryInfo factoryInfo = new DBFactoryInfo(factory);
         dbFactories.put(databaseInfo.getDatasource(), factoryInfo);

         String message = "Created EntityManagerFactory for " + databaseInfo.getDatasource() + ", user " + databaseInfo.getUsername() + ", at "
               + driverInfo.getJDBCUrl() + ".";
         Logger.log(JPAUtils.class, Level.INFO, message);
      }
```

where

```
   public MySQLDriverInfo(String ip, String schema) {
      this.ip = ip;
      this.schema = schema;
   }

   @Override
   public String getJDBCDriver() {
      String jdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      return jdbcDriver;
   }

   @Override
   public String getJDBCUrl() {
      //String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=<MYSQL_USER_NAME>&password=<MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD>"
      String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///my_db?cloudSqlInstance=test:us-east4:cloud-sql&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=me&password=*****";
      return dbUrl;
   }
```

but that will fail to create `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AppPU", properties);` as `Unable to build entity manager factory. NoSuchMethodError thrown. Possible issue with database or database data: com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.acquire(I)D`

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml to us to know what version of `Guava` you're using?

Comment: @CatherineO This project doesn't use `Guava` at all and that method error is coming from `mysql-socket-factory` dependency if so.

Comment: I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61735945/error-in-connecting-to-google-cloud-sql-com-google-cloud-sql-mysql-socketfactory) that might help. Also you may want to check the version of `mysql-socket-factory` that you use, it might be a version issue.

Comment: @CatherineO Yeah, I have tried to downgrade version and change connector to j-8 but did not help at all. Probably the app is too old to get it to work using instance connection name